# jsonSchema validating numerical keys by pattern

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

Could you help me, how I can validate "keys"(ex. "1","2","3") of list items in following json:

```
   {
    "list" : {
        "1" : {
            "element1" : "1",
            "element2" : "2"
        },
        "2" : {
            "element1" : "1",
            "element2" : "2"
        },
        ....
        "512" : {
            "element1" : "1",
            "element2" : "2"
        }
    }
   }
```

Please give me common examples to validate keys in json, too.

Comment: Maybe, my json is invalid  (https://spacetelescope.github.io/understanding-json-schema/reference/object.html)

Comment: http://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer you can edit, validate or beautify your json .

Comment: also what actually you mean by validate?

Comment: Yes, I mean by validate with using json schema.

Comment: Does above link work?

Comment: Thanks! It's very useful!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JSON Schema has three ways to constraint the property names of an object.

**properties**

The `properties` keyword allows you to set an exact match for property names.

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "1": { ... },
    "2": { ... },
    ...
  }
}
```

**patternProperties**

The `patternProperties` keyword constrains any property name that matches a regular expression to validate against a given schema.

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "patternProperties": {
    "[1-9][0-9]*": { ... }
  }
}
```

**propertyNames**

The `propertyNames` keyword constraints property names to match the given schema.

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "propertyNames": {
    "pattern": "[1-9][0-9]*"
  }
}
```

**Edit 12-19-2018** Improve answer, add missing `patternProperties`, add new (since original answer) option `propertyNames`.

Comment: This seems to be inconsistent with the feature of jsonschema called `patternProperties` ... https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/object.html#pattern-properties

Comment: Wow, you're right! I don't know what I was thinking when I wrote that. There's also `propertyNames` now as well. I'll update the answer when I get a chance.

Comment: how to add max/min length for strings and max-min range for integers?